# Connection with PACS in android

Tags: android, dicom, dcm4che

I used the sample code that uses dcmqr frim dcm4chee to connect and retrieve images from PACS.But the line dcmQR.addMatchingKey(new int[]{Tag.StudyID}, "1800688462"); gives unsupported operation exception.I am stuck here.Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Check your error tag (0x0000, 0x0902) from your response. 
This will generally have some explanation.

You might have not sent correct association transfer syntax.